# Make python login form with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to create a login form with python.
I don't know how to fix it
anyone can help with my error script ?

**main.py**

```
import requests, os, random, time
import pandas as pd

def login():
  userData = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
  df = pd.DataFrame(userData)
  username = df['username']
  password = df['password']

  print('Login Tools\n')
  user = input('Username : ')
  pasw = input('Password : ')

  if usr == username and psw == password:
    print('success')
  else:
    print('\nYour account is not registered yet!')
    print('please contact admin')

login()
```

**Data.csv**

```
username,password
admin,admin
user,12345
rann,rann123
stackoverflow,stackoverflow123
```

**Error Output**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 23, in <module>
    login()
  File "main.py", line 18, in login
    if user == username and pasw == password:
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1329, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 1):

`username` and `password` are `pd.Series`, so you can't do this, you want to check if the respective inputs are in each column.

Besides, with your approach, any existing username with any existing password works - which is not what you want.

Here is an alternative:

```
def login():
  userData = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
  df = pd.DataFrame(userData)

  print('Login Tools\n')
  user = input('Username : ')
  pasw = input('Password : ')
  
  matching_creds = (len(df[(df.username == user) & (df.password == pasw)]) > 0)

  if matching_creds:
    print('success')
  else:
    print('\nYour account is not registered yet!')
    print('please contact admin')
```